# Regex string with "$" symbol

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

I was using `StringBuilder.Replace()` to change some "keywords" to my own methods, but since it doesn't match the whole word I need to find a way to replace it correctly.

```
string example = "Hey $name! Welcome to $namewebsite!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(example);
sb.Replace("$name", "getName()");
sb.Replace("$namewebsite", "getWebSiteName()");
return sb;
```

Above the output will be "Hey getName()!, Welcome to getName()website!", so I'm trying to use RegEx to match the whole word.

```
string example = "Hey $name! Welcome to $namewebsite!";
example = Regex.Replace(example, "\b$name\b", "getName()");
example = Regex.Replace(example, "\b$namewebsite\b", "getWebSiteName()");
return example;
```

But since the "keyword" has the symbol "$" it doesn't work, at least that's what I think, because it doesn't replace any of the "keywords".

Of course it's just a small example of my code, I have like 30+ keywords starting with "$" to replace to methods names.

Comment: Did you try escaping it with `\$`?

Comment: Put a backslash in front of the `$` to escape it, i.e. use `"\$"`. Or alternatively `Regex.Escape("$name")`

Comment: When I use te Regex.Escape("$name") it keep replacing the $namewebsite to getName()website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here doesn't need to be solver with RegEx. It's the order in which you are doing the replacements. This is because the first search is a substring of the second. Switch them round and it will work.

```
string example = "Hey $name! Welcome to $namewebsite!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(example);
sb.Replace("$namewebsite", "getWebSiteName()");
sb.Replace("$name", "getName()");
return sb;
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/kHwHUT

Another way to solve this would be to put a delimiter at the END of the search string as well as the start. For example:

```
string example = "Hey $name$! Welcome to $namewebsite$!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(example);
sb.Replace("$name$", "getName()");
sb.Replace("$namewebsite$", "getWebSiteName()");
return sb;
```

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `$` is a special character in regular expressions which denotes the end of a string.  You need to escape it if you want to use it as a literal:

Try using `\$` instead of `$`.

For more information: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1